# What are control characters, why do they exist, and what are they used for?

Tags: unix, terminal, command-prompt, control-characters

When I am using the terminal, I will often press, for example, alt plus an arrow key, and instead of doing what I expect (usually moving the cursor) I get a "Control Character" like `[[A;` or something like that. What letters I get seems to be very context sensitive, its different if there is a program running in the foreground vs. actually at a prompt, its different during the boot sequence, and it seems to be different depending on which UNIX I'm using. I know what a few of them are for (`^C`, `^D`, `^Z`) but I have no idea what the rest are used for or where they came from, or why they haven't been gotten rid of yet.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#The_design_purpose

Comment: @devnull that seems to only be about ASCII control characters, which I understand much better than the `^[[A` type characters

Comment: read up about terminal escape sequences. Good luck.